# Import file to table error : Failure 2673

Tags: sql, database, csv, import, teradata

I'm trying to load an csv file (delimited by |) to a Teradata table using BTEQ.
Unfortunately I'm getting the error Failure 2673 The source parcel length does not match data that was defined. Any thoughts on what could be the cause of these error is appreciated. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Here is the table DDL:

```
    CREATE MULTISET TABLE DATABASE.EMPLOYEE ,NO FALLBACK ,
         NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
         NO AFTER JOURNAL,
         CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
         DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
         (
          EMP_ID VARCHAR(11) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          SEX CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC COMPRESS,
          BIRTHDATE CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC COMPRESS,
          LOAD_DT TIMESTAMP(6))
    PRIMARY INDEX ( EMP_ID );
```

BTEQ SCRIPT:

```
    .LOGON xxxxx/XXXXX,XXXXX
    .IMPORT VARTEXT '|' FILE='C:/XXXX/XXXX.csv' , skip = 1;
    .QUIET ON
    USING 
    (   EMP_ID VARCHAR(11)
    ,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30)
    ,MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(30)
    ,LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30)
    ,SEX CHAR(1)
    ,BIRTHDATE CHAR(10)
    ,LOAD_DT TIMESTAMP(6)
    )        
    INSERT INTO DATABASE.EMPLOYEE
        ( EMP_ID
    ,FIRST_NAME
    ,MIDDLE_NAME
    ,LAST_NAME
    ,SEX
    ,BIRTHDATE
    ,LOAD_DT
    )
    VALUES ( 
    :EMP_ID
    ,:FIRST_NAME
    ,:MIDDLE_NAME
    ,:LAST_NAME
    ,:SEX
    ,:BIRTHDATE
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
    .LOGOFF
    .QUIT
```

CSV File

```
EMP_ID|FIRST_NAME|MIDDLE_NAME|LAST_NAME|SEX|BIRTHDATE
00011111|Sam|Arthur|Heinz|F|1955-01-01
00022222|Liam||Carter|M|1914-04-11
00033333|Edward|Johnson|Johnson|M|1958-07-13
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error is generated because you define `LOAD_DT` in your `USING` clause and BTEQ is expecting a field to exist in your imported file. Instead it is encountering an `EOR` which results in the error that the source parcel length doesn't match what you have defined.

Try removing `LOAD_DT` from your using clause and either leave CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in your INSERT or change the `DEFAULT` of the column to be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

If I may make one suggestion I would correctly define the `BIRTHDATE` as a `DATE` and not a `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: I have deleted the column in the using part that does not have match in the csv file.. but i'm still getting the error.

Comment: Update: I tried changing the LOAD_DT to DATE, but it also did not work. I did some test and added another field which also contains a date value. The first (date) column I used CHAR(10), there still an error. I used VARCHAR(10) second (date) column, and it works. Any idea on how BTEQ converts the character length of the file. Thanks!